# ASP.NET web programming

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Good evening, I'm starting ASP.NET web programming under visual studio 2017. Obviously, visual studio has a source code and a design mode but I would have learned that the design mode is not too efficient from the point of view or a design carried out does not always appear to be in conformity in a browser after execution. is there a solution so that the rendering is executed in a browser conforms to the design? that's my concern. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any actual developer shop that uses the design mode for ASP.NET Web Forms. You should not rely on it, learn to use the source code view. Or better yet - don't use Web Forms. It's a dead framework.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the web page in google chrome